# Retrieving all files with GetItemsAsync without having to specify file types

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm trying to get a list of files from my WinRT device with the following code:

var folder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;

var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();

This returns a list of Folders and Files. 
The problem is that the file list only contains files which extensions I have added to the Package.appxmanifest

Is there a way to retrieve ALL files? like * . * ?

Comment: There is a way - Metro Commander does it.

Comment: @FilipSkakun I checked Metro Commander and actually it doesn't. It offers direct access to Music, Pictures and Videos library, it requires the user to manually add the disks and stores them to `FutureAccessList` and it allows the user to browse to a specific folder with `FolderPicker`.

Comment: Fair enough and that might be an acceptable answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a direct way to do it. According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) it can be done with Pictures, Music and Videos library but not with Documents library

> You must add File Type Associations to your app manifest that declare
>   specific file types that your app can access in this location.

If you get the user to select the folder with `FolderPicker`, you will get access to all items, though:

```
var picker = new FolderPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();
```

It is enough for the user to do it only once. You can then add the folder to [`FutureAccessList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) and store the token it returns:

```
var token = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
```

When the user runs the app next time you can use the token to get access to the folder again:

```
folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(token);
var items = await folder.GetItemsAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Damir and Filip. You both put me in the right direction. The FutureAccessList is persistant and you only need to add locations once. I now have full access to my surface!